# What is the underlying process of how a webpack build launches the entry point code?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I'm experimenting with webpack 4 in the process of upgrading from webpack 2, and have defined a web.config with two modules for the one entry point. I have created a separate runtime file. I also have the SplitChunks plugin being used to split out shared vendor code. So I have 3 bundles, app, vendor, and runtime.

When I load these bundles into a web page the entry point module does not appear to be getting "launched". Have tried specifying the runtime bundle first and also last in the list of scripts.

I have gone looking to see how the initial "module" (the entry point(s)) are actually "loaded" but I cannot see the process.

Can someone explain where I should be able to see this information in the generated code? For example, should I see a "require" of the module in the runtime source file? The runtime source file defines the function(modules) function top of file and then invokes it with an empty array -- is that correct?